# SSIS package for replacing the stored procedure with cursor and different servers with join clauses

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to create a ssis package for replacing the below stored procedures. It has join clauses, cursors and are using different servers. So I have been trying to figure out the solution for it. If anyone have any concepts so that I get rid of the linked server connection issue. Thank you in advance. Any kind of useful steps and hints. I really appreciate it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AUDIT_FILES] AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

 DECLARE
 @cmd nvarchar(4000)
, @working_dir nvarchar(240)
, @file_name nvarchar(240)
, @file_list nvarchar(2000)
, @table_name sysname
, @audit_count int
, @email_to nvarchar(MAX)
, @email_subject nvarchar(240)
, @email_body nvarchar(MAX)
, @email_attach nvarchar(240)
, @top_recs int
, @sql nvarchar(MAX);

BEGIN TRY
SET @working_dir = 'k:\sql\data\WWE037\audit';

SET @cmd = 'del /q "' + @working_dir + '*.*"';
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT;

IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','c_audit_tables') > -1 DEALLOCATE c_audit_tables;

DECLARE c_audit_tables CURSOR
FOR

SELECT
a.TABLE_NAME
, a.TOP_NUM_REC
FROM 
[CSVP0007\WWE037].Audit.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES i
INNER JOIN WebPM_Copy.dbo.AUD_TABLE_LIST a ON
  i.TABLE_NAME = a.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN [CSVP0007\WWE037].Audit.sys.tables t on 
a.TABLE_NAME = t.name
INNER JOIN [CSVP0007\WWE037].Audit.sys.partitions p ON
 p.object_id = t.object_id
GROUP BY a.TABLE_NAME, a.TOP_NUM_REC
HAVING SUM(rows) > 1
ORDER BY 1;

OPEN c_audit_tables;
FETCH c_audit_tables INTO @table_name, @top_recs;

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN
SET @file_name = @table_name + '.txt';
SET @audit_count = COALESCE(@audit_count,0) + 1;

SET @cmd = 'SELECT TOP {Recs} * INTO dbo.TMP_AUDIT_EXPORT FROM 
[CSVP0007\WWE037].Audit.dbo.{TableName}';
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd,'{Recs}',@top_recs);
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd,'{TableName}',@table_name);

IF OBJECT_ID('TMP_AUDIT_EXPORT') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE TMP_AUDIT_EXPORT;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;

EXEC util.dbo.usp_export_table
  @db_name         = 'wb_Copy'
, @schema_name     = 'dbo'
, @table_name      = 'TMP_AUDIT_EXPORT'
, @output_dir      = @working_dir
, @output_file     = @file_name
, @delimiter       = '|'
, @use_native_mode = 0
, @location_code   = 'DEV_Wb_COPY';

FETCH c_audit_tables INTO @table_name, @top_recs;
END

CLOSE c_audit_tables;
DEALLOCATE c_audit_tables;


SET @file_name = 'Audit_FCL_' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) + '.zip';
SET @file_list = @working_dir + '\*.txt';

EXEC BIA_Utils_User.dbo.usp_zip_files
@zip_dir      = @working_dir
, @zip_file     = @file_name
, @file_list    = @file_list
, @zip_password = NULL;

SET @email_subject = 'Wb Daily Audit Testing:  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
GETDATE(), 101)
SET @email_attach = @working_dir + '\' + @file_name;
PRINT @email_attach
SET @email_body = '*** Number of Audit File(s) To Be Reviewed:  ' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@audit_count);

EXEC Utils_User.dbo.usp_send_bia_mail
@profile_name = 'WB'
, @subject = @email_subject
, @body = @email_body
, @body_format = 'TEXT'
, @importance = 'NORMAL'
, @file_attachments = @email_attach
, @app_code = 'wb_app'
, @bnotify_app_group = 'Audit_Email';
 END TRY
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create a SSIS package for the stored procedure"?  SSIS can execute stored procedures on SQL Server directly.  Are you trying to replace the procedure with an SSIS package?  If not, then please be more specific about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Brian how to create a SSIS package for the above stored procedures. Yes, replacing with it. Thanks